# WebGL Unity Game freezes in random moment

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl

The game freezes and stops responding after a while (10-20 seconds) after starting. Most often this happens when performing active actions, such as interacting with UI buttons or turning objects on/off. At some point, the game simply stops responding to the player's actions, stops rendering new frames. With all this, everything is fine in the Editor.

The game consists of UI panels, most often the game freezes on the second of them, either after its appearance or after interacting with buttons (pointing the cursor, pressing)

Unity Version: 2022.3.4f1
Browser: Google Chrome

What should I pay attention to if everything is working fine in the Unity editor?

[image: UI Panel 1]
[image: UI Panel 2]

I tried to build the game also in the Unity 2021 version, but the game still freezes. I did a Development Build, but the console didn't show any errors, and the Unity profiler just stopped showing new frames.

Comment: any web errors?

Comment: No, there are no errors in the console

Comment: So not web browser errors in there just to be clear. Not unity.

Comment: Yes, there are no web browser errors here